# Count inversions with merge-sort

Tags: algorithm

I am reading "Introduction of Algorithm, 2nd edition".  It has an exercise, Problem 2.4

> Let A[1 n] be an array of n distinct numbers. If i < j and A[i] > A[j], then the pair (i, j) is     called an inversion of A.
>
> d. Give an algorithm that determines the number of inversions in any permutation on n elements in Θ(n lg n) worst-case time. (Hint: Modify merge sort.)

Then I found this solution in the Instructor's Manual

```
COUNT-INVERSIONS ( A, p, r)
inversions ← 0
if p < r
  then q ← ( p + r)/2
   inversions ← inversions +C OUNT-I NVERSIONS ( A, p, q)
   inversions ← inversions +C OUNT-I NVERSIONS ( A, q + 1, r)
   inversions ← inversions +M ERGE -I NVERSIONS ( A, p, q, r)
return inversions


MERGE -INVERSIONS ( A, p, q, r)
n1 ← q − p + 1
n2 ← r − q
create arrays L[1 . . n1 + 1] and R[1 . . n2 + 1]
for i ← 1 to n1
  do L[i] ← A[ p + i − 1]
for j ← 1 to n2
  do R[ j ] ← A[q + j ]
L[n 1 + 1] ← ∞
R[n 2 + 1] ← ∞
i ←1
j ←1
inversions ← 0
counted ← FALSE
for k ← p to r
  do 
  if counted = FALSE and R[ j ] < L[i]
    then inversions ← inversions +n1 − i + 1
    counted ← TRUE
  if L[i] ≤ R[ j ]
    then A[k] ← L[i]
    i ←i +1
  else A[k] ← R[ j ]
    j ← j +1
    counted ← FALSE
  return inversions
```

My question is, I found the variable counted really useless.  In the first if clause, it might be set to **TRUE**, but that means R[J] < L[i], so in the last else clause, it's going to be set back to **FALSE**.

Could anyone give me an example that could explain why *counted* is needed?

Comment: R[j] < L[i] <==> L[i] > R[j], not L[i] <= R[j].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `counted` variable is useless, since it will always be false when it's tested.

It looks like the author's intention was to avoid counting the same `R[j]` element twice. But they didn't notice that after counting `R[j]`, `j` will always be incremented due to going into the `else` clause, so there's no need for the precaution.